# Multi-threading in async rust - why is my code failing to parallelize?

Tags: rust, concurrency, rust-actix

I'm trying to intentionally exhaust an API limit (900 calls) by running the following function:

```
#[get("/exhaust")]
pub async fn exhaust(_pool: web::Data<PgPool>, config: web::Data<Arc<Settings>>) -> impl Responder {
    let mut handles = vec![];

    for i in 1..900 {
        let inner_config = config.clone();
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || async move {
            println!("running thread {}", i);
            get_single_tweet(inner_config.as_ref().deref(), "1401287393228038149")
                .await
                .unwrap();
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for h in handles {
        h.join().unwrap().await;
    }

    HttpResponse::Ok()
```

My machine has 16 cores so I expected the above to run 16x faster than a single-threaded function, but it doesn't. In fact it runs exactly as slow as the single-threaded version.

Why is that? What am I missing?

Note: the `move || async move` part looks a little weird to me, but I got there by following suggestions from the compiler. It wouldn't let me put async next to the first move due to `async closures being unstable`. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code will indeed run your `async` blocks synchronously. An `async` block creates a type that implements `Future`, but one thing to know is that `Future`s don't start running on their own, they have to either be `await`-ed or given to an executor to run.

Calling `thread::spawn` with a closure that returns a `Future` as you've done will not execute them; the threads are simply creating the `async` block and returning. So the `async` blocks aren't actually being executed until you `await` them in the loop over `handles`, which will process the futures in order.

One way to fix this is to use `join_all` from the `futures` crate to run them all simultaneously.

```
let mut futs = vec![];

for i in 1..900 {
    let inner_config = config.clone();
    futs.push(async move {
        println!("running thread {}", i);
        get_single_tweet(inner_config.as_ref().deref(), "1401287393228038149")
            .await
            .unwrap();
    });
}

futures::future::join_all(futs).await;
```

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that you're mixing multithreading and async in a way which causes all the work to be sequential: all your threads do is call `get_single_tweet` which is apparently an `async` function.

Now in a language like Javascript, `get_single_tweet` would create a *task*, which would return a *promise* symbolising the realisation of the task and run as soon as possible.

That's not how Rust works (or lots of other languages, incidentially, Python behaves much more like Rust than it does Javascript). In Rust, `get_single_tweet` just creates a *future*, it doesn't actually *do* anything, the future has to be [polled](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/future/trait.Future.html#runtime-characteristics) for things to happen: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b26b47e62e46b66b60844aabc2ea7be1

When does this polling happens? When the dynamic chain of await-ing reaches the top of the event loop.

Here the future is created in the thread, then returned from the thread, then `await`-ed when fetched from the `join`, so your fetches are not being run in threads, they're being run here:

```rust
    for h in handles {
        h.join().unwrap().await;
    }
```

which is completely sequential.

Now to fix this, you basically have two options, but the important bits is to keep to your realms:

- if you want to use threads, then the calls within them should be *blocking*
- otherwise, instead of using `thread::spawn` you probably want to use [`task::spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.6.1/tokio/task/fn.spawn.html) (or whatever the equivalent is in your runtime of choice), making sure you're using a multithreaded runtime is probably a good idea but here I'd assume `get_single_tweet` is performing IO work (e.g. fetching stuff from twitter), so a single-threaded runtime would probably yield most of the benefit already

`task::spawn` will (as its name indicates) create a *task* and return a handle to it, which is much closer to the behaviour of Javascript's `async` functions.